# PHP's DateTime-.add function works locally but not on server

Tags: php

I'm stuck on this and don't know what else to try. This line of code works fine locally but fails on server. There is no error message. I just get a blank page.

`$tempDate->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));`

Any idea why I would see this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The [add()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method requires PHP/5.3.0 or greater. Chances are that your host is using an older version.

Alternative code for PHP/5.2:

```
$tempDate->modify('+1 month');
```

Answer (score 0):

A blank page most likely means a fatal error.  Chances are you don't have error reporting enabled, so you see nothing. Just as a guess the version of PHP on your server is different then the version on your local.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to PHP 5.3, I had notices all over the place related to the use of the `date()` function because I hadn't set a default timezone, try setting one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

It might not be related, but it's worth trying. Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

You can reference the [list of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) to find the one that's right for you.

As far as the errors, try adding this to the beginning of your script or bootstrap file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Putting in the error reporting showed me that it didn't recognize the call to the add method. That led me to check the PHP version number and it's 5.2 on server.

Comment: It looks like [Álvaro G. Vicario's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8626252/398242) is the solution then.